# Custom claim for multiple realtime databases in Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I've tried to set custom claims for Admin users so they can access and change the data in 9 real-time databases `(custom claim: "admin": true)`.

The security rules for those 9 are the same, a user with the `"admin"` role can write and change the data for *`"admin_controller"`* in the database. But when I used an admin account, I could only change the data for database 1 and couldn't change `database 2, 3, 4, etc`. data (permission denied)

**Here's my code and my security rules:**

**Backend code:**

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var app_firebase = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
});

app.get('/setAdmin/:user_id', (req, res) => {
  var user_id = req.params.user_id;
  const additionalClaims = {
    admin: true,
  };
  admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user_id, additionalClaims)
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'successful' })
});
```

**Security rules:**

```
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "admin_controller": {
        ".write": "auth.uid !== null && auth.token.admin === true"
    },
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks Doug! I'm gonna fix that now.

Comment: You should know that security rules don't apply at all to backend code using the Firebase Admin SDK.  Backend code always bypasses all rules.  If you have frontend code that's accessing that database that isn't working the way you expect, you should show that as well, along with your evidence that the user is signed in and has the correct custom claims.

Answer (score 1):

Each Realtime Database instance in a Firebase project has its own set of security rules, so be sure to update the rules for all of your instances as shown in the documentation on [deploying the security rules for each instance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding#edit_and_deploy_for_each_instance).